# Как запустить класс в java. Android studio

Tags: java, android, классы, activity, google-maps

У меня есть фрагменты. Которые я переключаю с помощью выдвигающего окна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в манифест я добавил следующий код для карты.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Карта теперь у меня показывается, но в MapsActivity есть код которые показывает маркеры. Маркеры не работают. я так понимаю надо запустить теперь класс MapsActivity .

если запустить его вот так, то карта показывается и есть маркеры, но нет выдвигающейся панели.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAUYOT);

это добавить после super.onCreate() с вашим лейаутом , и должно заработать